# React useEffect how to run 1 or more function with single action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Сan anybody please help I'm stuck with this problem for a week already,

My app only work when :(3steps)

I pressed Buttons(buttons, checkboxes, radio) to change *listYear* , *listMonth* & listBranch(from other component)

Then I need to press button 1 to *setFilterYDate(listYear)* *setFilterMDate(listMonth)* & *setFilterBranch(listBranch)*

and then I need to press button 2 to execute function filter that require all data received from button 1

what I want is :(1step only)

When I press button to change *listYear* , *listMonth* & *listBranch* , I dont need to press button 1 and 2 again, it will automatically fire.

```
function content() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    let listYear = useSelector (state=>state.cardReducer.listYear)
    let listMonth= useSelector (state=>state.cardReducer.listMonth)
    let listBranch= useSelector (state=>state.cardReducer.listBranch)
    let originalData = useSelector(state=>state.cardReducer.originalData)

    const[meter,setMeter]=useState([])
    const[tableRow,setTableRow]=useState([])
    const[tableRow1,setTableRow1]=useState([])
    const[filterYDate,setFilterYDate]=useState([listYear])
    const[filterMDate,setFilterMDate]=useState([listMonth])
    const[filterBranch,setFilterBranch]=useState([listBranch])

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(getApi())
    },[])

    function filtered() {
        *this function will change tableRow & tableRow1*
    }

    function onButton1() {
        *this function will change all data required in function filtered*
        setFilterYDate([listYear])
        setFilterMDate(listMonth)
        setFilterBranch(listBranch)
    }

    function onButton2() {
        *this function run the filtered()*
        filtered()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run an effect when any of the listYear,listMonth or listBranch changes:

```
const filtered = useCallback(() => {
  //if statement checking listYear,listMonth,listBranch
  //dispatch action
}, [listBranch, listMonth, listYear]);
useEffect(() => filtered(), [filtered]);
```

If filtered doesn't dispatch an action but sets local state you can use the callback to prevent circular dependency:

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState([]);
const filtered = useCallback(
  () =>
    setSomeState((someState) => {
      //if statement checking listYear,listMonth,listBranch
      //return someState.filter
      //or return someState
    }),
  [listBranch, listMonth, listYear]
);
useEffect(() => filtered(), [filtered]);
```

But if filtered data is a locally filtered version of originalData then you should use selectors for that, I suggest using [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

Comment: Man thank you it might be the answer i was looking for